# How to reshape 4d array to 2d array in numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, reshape

I have a 4d array of shape like this. It has total 18*100 = 1800 rows and 30 dimensional outputs per row

```
(18, 100, 30, 1, 1)
```

i want to convert or reshape this into 2d array, the easiest way

```
(1800,30)
```

Sorry for being so naive with numpy, but please i am a novice user. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
numpy.reshape(input_in_4D, (1800,30))
```

Of course this just converts the input in the default order (meaning you "unroll" the input array from inner to outer); if you need special ordering, you should read up on slicing.

Comment: I understand this is pseudo code, but python does not accept variables that start with numbers. Also, this is not a valid input syntax for reshape it should be `np.reshape(input_4d, (1800, 3))` or the more popular `input_4d.reshape(1800,3)`.

Comment: it should be: np.reshape(input_4d, (1800, 30)) (I mean thirty not three).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reshape` method:

```
newArray = oldArray.reshape(1800,30)
```